# How to correctly assign and pass pointers through functions in C

Tags: c, memory-management

I have three files:

#### something.h

```
typedef struct {
    int size_t;
    char *c;
} p;

p ** createMatrix(int r, int c);

void printMatrix(p **matrix, const int r, const int c);
```

#### something.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "something.h"

p **
createMatrix(int r, int c)
{
    int rowsize=r*2+1;
    int colsize=c*2+1;

    /* memory alloc of rows */
    p **matrix=malloc(rowsize*sizeof(p *));
    int k;
    for(k=0; k<rowsize; k++)
    {
        /* memory alloc of columns */
        matrix[k]=malloc(colsize*sizeof(p));
    } 
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<rowsize; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<colsize; j++)
        {
            /* columns is between letters */
            if(j%2!=0)
        {   
                matrix[i][j].size_t=7;
                matrix[i][j].c=malloc(8*sizeof(char));
                strcpy(matrix[i][j].c,"       ");
        }
        else if(i%2==0 && j%2==0)
            {
                matrix[i][j].size_t=1;
                matrix[i][j].c=malloc(sizeof(char));
                *(matrix[i][j].c)='a';
            }
            else
            {
                matrix[i][j].size_t=1;
                matrix[i][j].c=malloc(sizeof(char));
                *(matrix[i][j].c)=' ';
            }
        }
    }       
    return matrix;
}

void
printMatrix(p **matrix, const int r, const int c)
{
    int rowsize=r*2+1;
    int colsize=c*2+1;
    printf("\n");
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<rowsize; i++)
    {
        printf("\t");
        for(j=0; j<colsize; j++)
        {
            if(matrix[i][j].size_t==1)
                printf("%c", *matrix[i][j].c);
            else
                printf("%s", matrix[i][j].c);

        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
 }
```

#### main.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "something.h"    

void
printMenufunction(p **matrix, int rows, int cols)
{
    int rowsize=rows*2+1;
    int colsize=cols*2+1;
    /* memory alloc of rows */
    matrix=malloc(rowsize*sizeof(p *));
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<rowsize; i++)
    /* memory alloc of columns */
        matrix[i]=malloc(colsize*sizeof(p));
    matrix=createMatrix(rows, cols);
}

int
main(void)
{
    int rows, cols;
    p **matrix;
    char *stringtemp;
    printf("ask for row and col in form (5x5):\n");
    scanf("%s", stringtemp);
    sscanf(stringtemp, "%dx%d", &rows, &cols);
    printMenufunction(matrix, rows, cols);
    printMatrix(matrix, rows, cols);
    return 0;
}
```

This simplified version throws me an segmentation fault. I don't understand where I'm trying to access memory not assigned? Can someone please explain it? (SSCCE)

Comment: Are you sure you allocated memory for the `c` member of your struct as part of the matrix allocation?

Comment: Yes I have done that and as I had problem with that before I know that it has not to do with the c member of the struct..

Comment: Also, why are you mallocating memory for nothing then leak it while reassigning it in `main()`?

Comment: Is it not necessary? Please elaborate, thank you..

Comment: `matrix=malloc(rowsize*sizeof(p *));` <- That shouldn't compile, it ought to be `malloc(rowsize * sizeof *p);`.

Comment: Why have you allocated memory twice ..no need to do that in main

Comment: on which line do you get the segmentation fault ?

Comment: I dont get it on any line, I just get segmentation fault 11. How can I find out on what line it is? Is there a way?

Comment: and answering your question -> I would guess you access the un-assigned memory in `....prints out something from every pos in the matrix....`. how do you do that?

Comment: @patriques, debug you code line by line and see where it throws you out (:

Comment: Use a debugger (e.g. `gdb`) or use `valgrind`.  Either will help.  At this stage, using the debugger might be the better for your learning.  Also, consider the merits of an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct (Compiling) Example](http://sscce.org/)). That would mean providing minimal code that fills in your triple dotted sections (so that the code you show can be compiled by those trying to help you) but still crashes.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with this code, except for the memory leak due to the fact that you allocate the matrix and then assign it to a matrix created with the function, without freeing the previously allocated matrix.

Comment: So how should I free the matrix after assigning it through a return statement. Seems difficult..